# kUbuntu kickstarter transparency

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I have a problem on Kubuntu, the kick-starter (start menu thing) was transparent till today, now its not transparent anymore, and I didn't change any settings or so, all my theme things are like before (transparent windows and so on) just the kick-starter is not transparent anymore. How can I get the transparency back? I am on an Acer C7 notebook.
I have another PC running ubuntu and there the kickstarter is transparent (with the same theme) oxygen black I think it's called.

Comment: By 'kickstarter' start menu, do you mean the menu which shows your choice of booting into Kubuntu or running Memtest? That's the GRUB2 menu. Please amend your question to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try:

1. Remove the Kickstarter menu from the panel and add it again. Do this by right-clicking on the icon and selecting "Remove this Application Launcher" then right-click on the panel, go to Panel Settings > Add Widget, and drag "Application Launcher" to where you normally keep it.
2. Reload the theme. Open System Settings and go to Workspace Appearance and Behavior > Workspace Appearance > Desktop Theme. Select a different theme and hit apply. Once it is done, select the theme you want and apply it again.
3. Sometimes it's just an issue with plasma. You can restart it by striking alt-f2 and typing the following:

   `kquitapp plasma-desktop && sleep 2 && plasma-desktop`

   Please note that this method could potentially cause other issues. If this doesn't work, you can also try logging out and logging back in again.

Hope this helps.